# CheckBox appears behind the groupbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

The purpose of my little program is when you click on a button you can make a checkbox appear on the winForm. I added a groupbox to make it look more "structured". Everything works fine but the problem is when I click on my button the Checkbox appears behind the groupbox and not on it.

Here is the code of the groupbox:

```
 GroupBox GrpGoals = new GroupBox();
        GrpGoals.Name = "GrpGoals";
        GrpGoals.Text = "Micro Goals";
        GrpGoals.Location = new Point(13, 4);
        Controls.Add(GrpGoals);
```

Here is the code to create the checkbox:

```
 private void CheckBoxes(string name)
    {

       CheckBox Chk = new CheckBox();
        Chk.AutoSize = true;

        Chk.Location = new Point(7, 21);
        Chk.Name = name;
        Chk.Text = name;

        Controls.Add(Chk);


    }
```

Comment: If you want the checkbox to be inside the groupbox then, `GrpGoals.Add(Chk); ` instead of Controls.Add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void CheckBoxes(string name)
{
    CheckBox Chk = new CheckBox();
    Chk.AutoSize = true;
    Chk.Location = new Point(7, 21);
    Chk.Name = name;
    Chk.Text = name;
    GrpGoals.Controls.Add(Chk);
}
```